# Chrome: some elements' background goes black randomly

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Sometimes, after the following:

- Reloading page
- Clicking other tab and returning
- Opening tab, then focusing another window on another screen

One of my divs background goes black. Sometimes it blinks for a second, sometimes it stays black until an action is performed on the page (scrolling, clicking etc.).

When inspecting, div computed background color is still white. Unchecking it, as well as changing any CSS prop in any element of the page, makes it white.

The issue is present only when hardware acceleration is enabled, I'm using Chrome version `84.0.4147.105` on macOS.

I assume it's a Chrome bug, but I'm not sure since it happens only to this one element so far. Did someone also encounter it? is there any way I can prevent it from happening?

Here's a screenshot:
[image: screenshot of black box bug]

I also found fairly recent issue on [Chrome support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/39969797?hl=en).

These are CSS styles applied to the element, if that makes any difference.

```css
.element {
  background-attachment:scroll;
  background-clip:border-box;
  background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-image:none;
  background-origin:padding-box;
  background-position-x:0%;
  background-position-y:0%;
  background-repeat-x:;
  background-repeat-y:;
  background-size:auto;
  bottom:0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  color:rgb(102, 102, 102);
  display:block;
  font-family:Roboto,
  "Helvetica Neue",
  Helvetica,
  Arial,
  sans-serif;
  font-size:14px;
  font-weight:400;
  height:781px;
  left:1660px;
  line-height:20px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
  margin-right:0px;
  margin-top:0px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  padding-bottom:0px;
  padding-left:0px;
  padding-right:0px;
  padding-top:0px;
  position:fixed;
  right:0px;
  text-size-adjust:100%;
  top:91px;
  transition-delay:0s;
  transition-duration:0.2s;
  transition-property:right;
  transition-timing-function:ease;
  width:260px;
  z-index:9;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: insert your html pls

Comment: Hi Michal, you need to show a [reprex], otherwise we can only guess...

Comment: I tried to reproduce it but couldn't. It also does not always appear black, once in every 20 reloads, and it stays black once every 100 reloads or something. I cannot share HTML here unfortunately.

Comment: On Windows similar problems (and others, duh) occur with too many tabs/browsers open or other graphically intensive processes running in the background. Just y'day Google Earth messed up my browsing (plus 3 open browser and 100 plus tabs). Dunno how macOS/iOS handles this. After closing G.Earth the problems were resolved. So, no more gaming during office hours???

Comment: That could be the issue, page is not the lightest too. Thank you for your input.